# Invalid sender, insufficient funds, nonce too low when sending raw signed transaction on Rinkeby via JSON-RPC (Infura)

Tags: json-rpc, infura, signature, sendsignedtransaction

I am writing a C++ program to interact with Ethereum using JSON-RPC calls to an Infura node. I am trying to send a signed transaction using "eth_sendRawTransaction" on the Rinkeby network as documented [here](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum#operation/eth_sendRawTransaction) and [here](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth-sendRawTransaction) (though I am not sure which page is correct, since it seems they contradict each other).

Here is an example of what I am sending:

`{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["0xF86A808501A13B8600825208941A6F7D959748B43D0B540386D0F27AF02A632CEA8638D7EA4C6800801BA08D5D29CE28B4115F971D8AAFEF7B007C7C1C322229C673CD9F28E4AC80F72D03A0D1DCF597678B296A5199224C53CBF6A550D08EBC812C0EC476A375E928CABF28"]}`

For some reason, I have had varied levels of success. Despite not changing the code at all, the errors alternate between three of the same errors, as an example below:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value"}}`

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"invalid sender"}}`

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value"}}`

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"nonce too low"}}`

The key point here is that none of those things are actually true. I always get the nonce by calling eth_getTransactionCount, and I've also tried just hard-coding it to a higher number. The funds are definitely not insufficient; my account has 0.9 eth and I'm only ever trying to send less than 0.1. And the sender should not be invalid (whatever that means?) because the signature it produces is correct. I know this because I had successfully sent a signed transaction three times, but even then it seemed random and after very negligible modifications to my code (which I have since reverted) I am unable to successfully send a transaction again. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example of values I am encoding:

```
TX tx;
tx.chainId = "0x4";
tx.nonce = nonce;
tx.gasPrice = "0x01a13b8600";
tx.gasLimit = "0x5208";
tx.to = myAddress;
tx.value = "0x38D7EA4C68000";
tx.data = "0x0";
tx.gasPremium = "0x0";
tx.feeCap = "0x5208";
```

I am using the code from [this repository](https://github.com/Kidades/hwwallet). This is how I am encoding the transaction:

```
string serialized = hexToRlpEncode(tx.nonce) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.gasPrice) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.gasLimit) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.to) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.value) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.data);

` if(!initial) {
    serialized += hexToRlpEncode(tx.v)+
                hexToRlpEncode(tx.r)+
                hexToRlpEncode(tx.s);
}`
```

I know this creates a "legacy" transaction but I did get it to update the blockchain this way a few times. I am also confused because if you look at the docs for things like [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction) or [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#eth-accounts-signtransaction) they will tell you to include the chainId in the transaction, but the Infura links I mentioned state do not state you need to do that. Are these errors happening because I am not including the chainId, or because I am not encoding the EIP-1559 stuff as well? If so, in what order to I encode these things? The Infura docs don't tell me how to do that. My own attempts at just trying it anyway have gotten responses like this one:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"rlp: input list has too many elements for types.LegacyTx"}}`

The above message occurs when I encode the chainId after everything else. And the below message occurs when I try to send a dynamic transaction:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"transaction could not be decoded: could not decode RLP components: could not decode list item 3 to Address: invalid address: 0x38D7EA4C6800"}}`

Where 0x38D7EA4C6800 is tx.Value, as seen here (which is the 4th value in the list, not the 3rd):

```
string serialized = hexToRlpEncode(tx.nonce) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.gasLimit) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.to) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.value) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.data) +
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.gasPremium)+
    hexToRlpEncode(tx.feeCap);
```

So maybe those are two different questions in one, but the point is that I'm having trouble getting the transaction to send (the signature it produces is correct). I don't know why I can run the same exact code and get different error messages, nor do I know why it once worked several times in a row and why I can't get the code to work again. The only thing I can guess is that the signature has randomness in it and that randomness affects the tx data that I send to Infura, which results in different responses... but the randomness is necessary, so that can't be it. Everything else is the same. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

I know I have a lot of questions so let me try and summarize them:

- Why do I get different error messages without changing the code between runs? Do I need to fix them individually, or just try fixing the fact that I get alternating messages?
- What exactly does "invalid sender" actually mean? Am I really having a problem with that, and if so how do I go about fixing it?
- Do I need to specify the chainId? If so, how do I do that?
- Do I need to make the transaction EIP-1559 compatible? If so, how do I do that?

It's frustrating because I had actually gotten it to work and now I don't know what I need to change to get it working again. Even when I first tried, it seemed to work only after changing arbitrary parts of code. It's possible I'm not sending the right combination of numbers (i.e. too low/high gas, too high/low value, too high/low nonce, etc.) and I'm just not understanding what I should be sending. I've tried thinking of everything and I will still try but I figured I might as well ask here too.

**EDIT:** Still not solved, but here is some more info. I got it to send transactions again somehow, but it also stops working just as easily. I have some code "TestTransaction(privateKey)" which sends crypto from a given wallet. When I call for instance Test(X) it works, then I change it to Test(Y) and it doesn't work. So I literally just hit undo on my keyboard to make it Test(X) again and yet it no longer works, even though it worked a minute before. The errors I get still cycle through the different messages, even though I'm not changing any code at all in my program.

Comment: The signed transaction gives an error using this https://flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx/.

Comment: @Ismael That link is really helpful for debugging, thank you.